# GRUB: Is there a way to pre-determine which OS to boot to, before the reboot?

Tags: dual-boot, boot

I imagine this doesn't have a workable solution yet, but would like to know if anyone has tried:

On Mac systems, there's an app for dual boot, from MacOS to boot to Windows on the next reboot, and from Windows there's also an app to next time boot back to MacOS. 
Is there a way this can be done with GRUB/UEFI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `grub-reboot` command, it sets to which operating system it will reboot the next time. Someone asked a similar question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43196/how-can-i-tell-grub-i-want-to-reboot-into-windows-before-i-reboot) and it seems you have to configure some stuff for this to work correctly. After you do this you just type `grub-reboot <entry>`, if you press <kbd>tab</kbd> before typing the entry and it will show you the list of entries on GRUB.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is the right answer, and I'll give it a shot. No way to implement a similar way to boot back into linux from windows, right?

Comment: I was thinking that would be the next problem. But sadly I don't think there is an easy way of doing this because Windows can't recognize a Linux hard drive unless you install some extra software and GRUB configuration in the end is all about editing some files on your Linux partition. 

If you install something to mount ext4 drives on windows, and find out which files need editing you may be able to write a script to do it. But in the end its so much trouble that it's just not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following post:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/485726/set-the-grub-default-os-dual-boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-14-04

That worked for me. However as per description on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

"This page describes how to set up your computer in order to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows. Warning /!\ While there are some benefits to dual-booting (e.g. better performance for a native install), it is not recommended. Instead, it is best to do a native install of Ubuntu, and then virtualize the other operating system."

I say so because then after I use dual boot and get frustrated to reboot my laptop every time I configure a host in linux and VirtualBox running Windows 7 and XP.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You should try to include more content from the source of your links, to provide a more helpful answer.